# Xslt Extension Objects- Getting Context

Tags: .net, xslt

i'm using `XsltArgumentList.AddExtensionObject` with sucess.
The problem is when i call the functions from the xslt, they only get the arguments i pass.
How can i get the context (what node is being processed).

I am using `XslTransform.Transform (myXPathDoc, xslArgs, myWriter);` to start the transformation..

I heard about `SetContext` and `RegisterCustomFunction` but they only seem to work on `XPathExpression` objects...

Thanks

Comment: Please post the XSLT and the extension function, so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no documented way for an extension function to implicitly access the context node**.

***Pass it as a parameter***.

*For example*:

`<xsl:value-of select="extFn:MyExtensionFunction(.,'A',./code,./date)"/>`

You will need to modify the code of the extension function: add a new parameter, which must be the first in order, and it is via this new parameter that the extension function gets the current node.

Comment: Dang. How do i pass it as a parameter?

I Have

<xsl:value-of select="extFn:MyExtensionFunction('A',./code,./date)"/>

Comment: @Joaozinho-das-Couves: See the updated solution for example. :)

Comment: well almost, what i actually wanted was not the data node, but the actual xslt context node.

In the end what i want is when there is an exception thrown by my function i want to say wich xslt node caused the exception (my function is used like 10 times in a xslt and depending on the parameters it can throw an exception)

Comment: @Joaozinho-das-Couves: `.` *is* the context node -- not the "data node". This is exactly what you say you wanted.

Comment: @Dimitre: In XSLT 2.0 is explicitly defined that there is no access to context node for stylesheet functions..

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, this is why I am telling the OP to pass the context node as a parameter.